# best way to create tree billboard

Tags: rendering

So I'm making a project in Unreal engine and I'm preparing assets from Blender, it has few vegetation mesh which are over 1M polygon which I can't use in unreal so I wanted to make it's billboards but I don't know how to do that

[image: From Internet]

the image I attached shows what it is, basically taking a high poly vegetation, rendering it from a few angles and then combining it

but Is it possible to make billboards which can work regardless of lighting conditions (day/night cycle)

Comment: Not enough information. At least add an image so that folks can see what you're talking about. You can edit your question and drag and drop images into the edit field.

Comment: Check this article: https://80.lv/articles/how-to-fake-a-large-scale-forest-in-blender/

Comment: ... oh, the video is already linked in Crantisz's link but I leave it here. It's [How to Fake a Large Scale Forest in Blender / Part 1](https://youtu.be/BtUS8QTsVZA). With the Sapling add-on you can create a tree, then render out the images for the billboard. The normal map makes it interact with light.

Comment: thanks a lot @Crantisz & Blunder I know I'm late but I ran into a few problems and then ported it to UE5 without You guys I might have smoked my gpu by now